# How to combine a regular JSS class with Material-UI's classes override feature using classnames

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to assign multiple classes to an element in React, using the [classnames](https://github.com/JedWatson/classnames) package, along with Material-UI's ["overriding with classes"](https://material-ui-next.com/customization/overrides/#overriding-with-classes) approach.

[Here](https://material-ui-next.com/demos/drawers/#persistent-drawer) is an example from MUI's documentation where they use classnames to assign multiple classes to an element (expand to see the source code in the example).

What I'm trying to do is combine one regular class I have created with JSS, and one that needs to override the MUI class. Here are the classes:

```
const styles = {
    insetListItemText: { // This will be used to target MUI's class
        '&:first-child': {
            paddingLeft: '1em',
        },
    },
    link: { // This is just a normal JSS class
        textDecoration: 'underline',
        textDecorationColor: '#ccc',
    },
}
```

Here I'm attempting to use classnames to apply both of these classes:

```
// import classNames from 'classnames'
<ListItemText
    inset
    classes={
        classNames({
            inset: classes.insetListItemText,
            [classes.link]: true
        })
    }
>
    List item text
</ListItemText>
```

I'm just having trouble figuring out how to combine the two methodologies syntactically. Any ideas?!

Answer (score 0):

I reckon you almost get there. Basically, `classes` prop doesn't expect a string of class names (which is what `classnames` return) but a key-pair object of predefined `keys` and your customise class names.

In the docs: https://material-ui-next.com/api/list-item-text/ `LisItemText` accept these values as keys of the `classes` prop: `root`, `inset`, `dense`, `primary`, `secondary`, `textDense`. So your JSX should looks like:

```
<ListItemText
    inset
    classes={{
      inset: [Name of your jss clases go here]
    }}
>
    List item text
</ListItemText>
```